# Pymongo bulk inserts not working

Tags: mongodb, collections, mongodb-query, pymongo, bulkinsert

I am following the tutorial http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html for bulk inserts. However, I am getting the error that I have listed below. What am I missing? The reviews_array is a json_array

```
client = MongoClient()
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.is_proj

db_handle = db.reviews


self.db_handle.insert_many(reviews_array)
```

The Error:

```
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'insert_many' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

Answer (score 9):

In pymongo, **before V3.0**, you use [`insert`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert) for both single-doc and bulk insert. If you pass a document, it performs a single-insert, and if you pass a different iterable (list, generator), it performs bulk insert.

`insert_many()` does not exist in pymongo before V3.0.

**In pymongo V3.0,** they introduced [`insert_many`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many) and [`insert_one`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one), and the use of the plain `insert` is deprecated.

Comment: How can bypass document validation? Pymongo returns a argument error

Comment: @Hugo you should post a new question with all the details.

Answer (score 1):

I also got this error. While shx2's answer is right here, i got the error because i was using mongoengine and tried insert_many on the database, and it is a collection method, so it makes sense to do conn[database][collection].insert_many(iterable) and not conn[database].insert_many(iterable).